# Can't get downloadablePlot shiny module from periscope working

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, periscope

I am trying to use the downloadablePlot module from periscope in a Shiny app. Reprex:

```
library(shiny)
library(periscope)
ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot"),
  downloadablePlotUI("object_id1",
                     downloadtypes = c("png"),
                     download_hovertext = "Download the plot and data here!",
                     height = "500px",
                     btn_halign = "left")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot<-renderPlot(plotInput())
  plotInput <- function() {
    ggplot(cars, aes(x=speed, y=dist))+geom_point()
  }
  callModule(downloadablePlot,
             "object_id1", 
             logger = periscope:::fw_get_user_log(),
             filenameroot = "mydownload1",
             aspectratio = 1.33,
             downloadfxns = list(png = plotInput),
             visibleplot = plotInput )
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The following displays the plot twice, without any download button instead of showing the plot and a download button.

TIA :)

UPDATE: Had a little nosy in the source code - there was CSS that hid the button (??) which I removed.